# how to recall output of "xtabs" function in r?

Tags: r, export, reshape

I have a big data set which has lat,lon,time and, value. I use "xtab" function to totally reshape my data set matrix and convert it to the form I needed for my purpose. Now the problem is that I don't know how to recall or export the new output matrix which has been created by "xtabs" function.

this is part of my original data set:

```
number  lon lat month   value
1   -124.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
2   -123.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
3   -122.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
4   -121.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
5   -120.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
6   -119.5  31.5    1980.1  NA
```

this is the command line:

```
AMS <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\wildfire.Acres.csv",header=TRUE)
xtabs(value~lat+lon+month, data=AMS, exclude="")
```

this is part of the output:

```
,   ,   month   =   1980.1  

lon             
lat -124.5  -123.5  -122.5  -121.5  -120.5
31.5    0   0   0   0
32.5    0   0   0   0
33.5    0   0   0   0
34.5    0   0   0   0
35.5    0   0   0   0
36.5    0   0   0   0.1
37.5    0   0   0.1 0
38.5    0   0   0.2 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can just put the new matrix in another object and work with it ? `mat2 <- xtabs(value~lat+lon+month, data=AMS, exclude="")` ?

Comment: In `R` everything is an object.  When you execute a command on the console, you are seeing the print of that object.  If you want to actually _do something_ with the results, you need to save them.  You this using the assign operators (ie, `<-` and/or `=`).  To access a specific part of your matrix, use the `subset` operators, such as `mat[, , month==1980.1]`

Comment: @juba; @Ricardo Saporta; I did this and I put it in new object but the problem is that when I open the new matrix in Excel for example surprisingly it has the format of the old matrix!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not a matrix, it's an array. To access the "1980.1" slice of that array you first assign the result to a named object:

```
res <- xtabs(value~lat+lon+month, data=AMS, exclude="")
res[ ,  , "1980.1"]
```

You say you "opened the result in Excel". Did you cut and paste the screen output?

When you use `write.csv` (a function that is not designed to output arrays) with a simple 3x3x3 matrix the third dimension is lost:

```
res <- array(1:27, dim=c(3,3,3))
write.csv(res,"res1980.1.csv") 

# What my text editor shows:
"","X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9"
"1",1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25
"2",2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26
"3",3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27
```

I remain unclear what output or result is desired.

Comment: @ DWin; No I used write.csv command :

Comment: now when use your command and then write.csv the same thing happens again. I use this command and at the end I have old matrix again!!                                   write.csv(res,"res1980.1.csv")

Comment: You are corresponding with us as though we can see your screen. We have not idea what "the old matrix" looks like. Please be more specific and expansive in your questions and replies..